# Iframe - Problems with centering

Tags: html, css, position

I have some problems with an iframe centering.

The code is setup to keep the same ratio, so it is 100% reposonsive.
This also causes VERY LIMITED possibilies for adding formattiong and - Centering
I have tired to both add a container box, and changing the css styling but I cant seam to get it to work...

any idears

```
<div class="background background_video">
        <div id="video_container">
            <div class="youtube-video-container">
                <iframe class="youtube-video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8aGhZQkoFbQ"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

.youtube-video-container {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.youtube-video {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep the youtube-video-container and iframe responsive. Use css `.background_video { text-align: center; } .video_container { display: inline-block; }` to center it in the parent divs. Please give some more css about video_container if this does not work.

Comment: It just dissaper if I do that

Comment: See my 'bron' solution below ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.youtube-video-container {
  height: 300px; // some height
  position: relative;
}

.youtube-video {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

as I correct understand question

Comment: with a fixed container height the iframe is not responsive.

Comment: See that's the problem, that form is not resonsive and it has to be 100% responsive

Answer (score 0):

FROM ANOTHER POST I FOUND...
Thanks for the trying to help anyways guys!

Without knowing the width/height of the positioned1 element, it is still possible to align it as follows:

```
EXAMPLE HERE

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  /* position the top  edge of the element at the middle of the parent */
    left: 50%; /* position the left edge of the element at the middle of the parent */

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* This is a shorthand of
                                         translateX(-50%) and translateY(-50%) */
}
```

It's worth noting that CSS Transform is supported in IE9 and above. (Vendor prefixes omitted

Comment: It doesn't work cross browser thought, so do anyoe know a webkit for that

Answer (score 0):

In this responsive 16:9 youtube css, all parents of #video_container have to be set to an height 100%.

Click on Run code, then 'Full page' to see the result.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.background_video {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
#video_container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
.youtube-video-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.youtube-video-container::before  {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.youtube-video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background background_video">
  <div id="video_container">
    <div class="youtube-video-container">
      <iframe class="youtube-video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8aGhZQkoFbQ"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```